# не приходит код подтверждения pyrogram и не выдает ошибку

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

я запрашиваю код. код не приходит И **НЕ ВЫДАЁТ ОШИБКУ** И ЕЩЁ **КАК-ТО ПОКАЗЫВАЕТ** `phone_code_hash`

```
async def send_code(app_name, phone_number, api_id, api_hash):
    client = Client(app_name, api_id, api_hash, phone_number=phone_number)
    await client.connect()
    code = await client.send_code(phone_number)
    print(code)
```

вот `code`

```
{
    "_": "SentCode",
    "type": "SentCodeType.APP",
    "phone_code_hash": "0ab5613004b6dc2724"
}
```

я пробовал на 2 аккаунтах но точно так же

Answer (score 0):

Ты получил ограничение на отправление сообщений с этого IP адреса. Используй прокси и все заработает снова. Мне помогло подключиться к другой сети wifi. Через время ограничение должно спасть